# TrackJS: how to prevent attackers from using my token?

Tags: security, trackjs

I'm planning to use TrackJS to monitor errors from my app but by reading the [documentation](https://docs.trackjs.com/browser-agent/installation/#auto-install) it seems that my private token must be exposed on the browser:

```
<script src="https://cdn.trackjs.com/agent/v3/latest/t.js"></script>
<script>
  window.TrackJS && TrackJS.install({
    token: "YOUR_TOKEN"
  });
</script>
```

The API have limit of request that I can do. So, an attacker could stole my token by reading the source code and make many requests to TrackJS API using it. How can I prevent this type of attack?

Answer (score 1):

The token is not actually "private".  It's fine for others to see it.  It's no different than a Google Analytics account/token, or any other third party service identifier. It's just a way for us know which account to put the errors in.

Your account [does have API keys](https://docs.trackjs.com/data-api/#authentication) and other things that shouldn't be shared, but your installation token is not one of them.